# Send files with scp while being logged on cluster interface

Tags: ssh, scp, cluster, torque

I have to do some work on a Torque cluster where I log on a User interface via ssh. I transfer files to my directory of the cluster and get files from the directory by using scp in my normal terminal (with "user@homecomputer:~$ scp...").

What I want to know is if it's possible to use the scp command also from the user interface of the cluster (the one with "[user@host ]$"? I hope I could explain what I am looking for - I am not a very experienced user of the terminal and especially of the technical terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible directly. You can copy files via scp to the server because the server is listening on port 22 using a static IP. You can't scp from server to home computer since , you dont have sshd and static IP for home computer.